# What is best practice to create a small database in python?

Tags: python, database

If I want to create a small database in Python, what would be the best practice to do it?

For instance, if I want to store output from Cisco's command "sh ip route" in a database,

```
O       1.1.1.1 [110/2] via 10.0.0.1, 00:00:23, FastEthernet0/0
```

stores these values:

1.1.1.1 —> next hop, outgoing interface, source (like O, C, S)

1. Using postgreSQL, mySQL
2. A nested dictionary something like this {'1.1.1.1':{*next hop*: {*outgoing interface*: *source*}}
3. a dictionary with a list as a value
   {'1.1.1.1':[*next hop, outgoing interface, source*]}
4. Any other option?

I feel that SQL would be the best solution but if not SQL, what is another option?

Comment: Just use sqlite3 module in python https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Sure! That sounds good. Between 2 and 3, which practice is better?

Comment: You can't store a Python dictionary directly in sqlite3, so you need to convert your Python dictionary to a JSON string.

Comment: If you are considering nosql, MongoDB uses PyMongo to connect with Python: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/

Comment: No, I meant if I don't use sqlite3 at all and choose between a nested dictionary or dictionary with a list as a value. In this case I have to create a temporary database available only during runtime.

Comment: I suggest trying pydblite. Served me well over time. http://www.pydblite.net/en/PyDbLite.html

Answer (score 7):

routing tables look to have a form more similar to documents that relational tables in a RDBMS like Postgres or MySQL.

I would prefer to use a document oriented database in this case. Regarding which database to use it depends on your deployment scenario and application architecture.

If your aim is a database server which can be accessed via the network then Mongo is a very good choice. If you are going for a single-node application which will access the data only locally, then you can have a look in TinyDB.

With TinyDB your code would look like:

```
 from tinydb import TinyDB, Query

 db = TinyDB('/path/to/db.json')
 db.insert({ 'Destination': '1.1.1.1',
             'NextHop': '10.0.0.1',
             'A': '*',
             'P': 'B',
             'Prf': 170',
             ....
            })
```

And finally look for the individual routes as:

```
  route = Query()
  db.search(route.Destination == '1.1.1.1')
  # [{'Destination': '1.1.1.1','NextHop': '10.0.0.1','A': '*',...}]
```

or get all of them at once:

```
  db.all()
```

Hope it helps!